# Caching a tuple to a value without new instance creation

Tags: java, caching, guava

I would need to implement a caching of tuple of strings to a value.

The problem is that I don't want a new class instance to be created when I retrieve a value from cache.

- If concatenation of strings is used still new string would be created
- If new class StringTuple is used still it would need to be created

I can use Guava Cache or HashMap but memory consumption and performance should be optimized.

What would you recommend?

Comment: Is it really going to be used so often that the creation of the `StringTuple`s for look-up will have a significant impact on the memory allocation and young GC? These would be small, short-lived objects anyway, so I'd make sure to measure the effect before trying to optimize. Otherwise you could use a `Map<String, Map<String, T>>` (with as many levels as needed for the tuple), but it would be more painful to use **and** the memory footprint of the resulting structure could be much higher than the simpler one, so you'd pay a GC price anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first reaction when I see a question like this (and I ask these questions too) is to look for the hidden assumptions.

It seems to me that there's an implicit assumption here that creating these short lived objects just to do a lookup is a pretty expensive operation.

So, I wrote up a quick little benchmark where I made two caches, one based on a custom complex key, and the other with string concatenation. Each had 1,000,000 entries. For the actual tests, then, I did 1,000,000 lookups.

What I found was that the results were pretty close, around 500ms on my machine, with the string concatenation being on average about 7.5% slower.

I also added a third test in which I did the lookups by a complex key, but reused the same object, only mutating the values. I found this to be very comparable, at about 3.5% fast than creating new objects for each lookup.

My benchmark may not be hugely rigorous, but I think it shows that these methods are close enough that I would not shy away from creating a small, short-live object for the purpose of performing a lookup.